# Javascript drag drop error while dragging second times

Tags: javascript

```
    drop = (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        console.log(data)
    }

    allowDrop = (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    drag = (ev) => {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    drop = (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        let item = document.getElementById(data);
        var cln = item.cloneNode(true);
        ev.target.appendChild(cln);
    }

    //   html part 3
    <li onDrop={(event) => this.drop(event)}  onDragOver={(event) => this.allowDrop(event)} style={{ height:'100px', border:'2px solid red' }}> 
        <span title={this.state.dt2_sub_group_description}><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> {this.state.dt2_sub_group_name}</span>
    </li>


    // html part 1
    <ul className="nested nested-col">
        <li style={{ cursor:'pointer' }} id="drag1" draggable="true" onDragStart={(event) => this.drag(event)}><i className="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> col 1</li>
        <li style={{ cursor:'pointer' }} id="drag2" draggable="true" onDragStart={(event) => this.drag(event)}><i className="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> col 2</li>
        <li style={{ cursor:'pointer' }} id="drag3" draggable="true" onDragStart={(event) => this.drag(event)}><i className="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> col 3</li>
        <li style={{ cursor:'pointer' }} id="drag4" draggable="true" onDragStart={(event) => this.drag(event)}><i className="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> col 4</li>
    </ul>

    // html part 2
    <div className="droppable" onDrop={(event) => this.drop(event)}  onDragOver={(event) => this.allowDrop(event)} style={{ margin:'5px' }}>

    </div>
```

Here i have shared my code.

I am dragging list elements from (html part 1) to (html part 2)

Again once the li element is available at (html part 2) again i am dragging the same to (html part 3)
that time i am getting like ev.dataTransfer.getData is null but first time drag drop working but, once i am done i amdragging again the dragged elemnt to

(html part 3)

That time i am getting error

Please have a  look